# Get the excerpt by page ID from another blog in a wordpress multisite?

Tags: multisite, excerpt, switch-to-blog, get-post

I am trying to get the first paragraph on a page where page ID=2 and blog ID=1. I want to display this paragraph on a page in blog id=2. I have added the following code to the template page.

```
//gets active blog
global $blog_id;
switch_to_blog(1);
$pageid = 2; //author page
$post = get_post( $pageid ); 
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $pageid );
//$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);  //filters just the post content
echo "<div id='about-alandracl'>";
echo $excerpt;
//echo $content;
echo "</div>";
restore_current_blog();
```

I have the following in the functions.php file of each theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 206 );
```

This is the page where I am grabbing the content from: http://alandracl.com/author/
This is the page I want to display the first paragraph (without the image) on: http://alandracl.com/the-sussex-deal/
(under the about section on this page).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used substr in php to limit the characters. Here is the code that solved my problem:

```
//gets active blog
global $blog_id;
switch_to_blog(1);

$pageid = 2;
$post = get_post( $pageid ); 
$content = $post->post_content;
echo "<div id=''>";
echo substr( $content, 0, 380);
echo "</div>";
restore_current_blog();
```

Answer (score 0):

you already called `get_post()` then why you are not getting the excerpt from post data, like this.

```
$post = get_post( $pageid ); 
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

// get post content
$content = $post->post_content;
```

for more information about `get_post()` see the WordPress [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)